# Is there a word for women who use prostitutes?

Tags: terminology, slang, colloquialisms

Men who use prostitutes are colloquially called *johns*.  Is there a specific word for women who use prostitutes?

Comment: _Johanna_ may pass, simply as a feminine equivalent of john. My theory is, if others understand its meaning, then it's a word.

Comment: I've seen "jane" used once or twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen ***jane*** is used for a *female john* but it is not as common.

*John* is used for men, however you can find gender neutral definitions of the term as well. For example, *Newspeak (Routledge Revivals): A Dictionary of Jargon (By Jonathon Green)* mentions that it is used for both male and female.

[image]